# VueRouter - Fetching Before Navigation - Multiple AJAX

Tags: vuejs2, axios, vue-router

I would like to use the `beforeRouteEnter` guard so I can be sure my data is loaded before going to a page. I read the example you can find [here](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/data-fetching.html) in the `vue-router` documentation.

#### Current situation

I'm more or executing two `AJAX` calls to get some data in the `created` lifecycle event.

```
export default {

    created() {
      const _this = this;
      axios.get('/getCompanyDetails').then((response) => {
            _this.private.company_details = response.data
        });
      axios.get('/getusers').then((response) => {
            if(response.data){
                _this.private.company_users =  response.data;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

#### What I try

```
 beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {

        function getCompanyDetails() {
            return  axios.get('/getCompanyDetails')    
        }

        function getUsers() {
            return axios.get('/getusers');
        }

        axios.all([getCompanyDetails(), getUsers()])
            .then(axios.spread(function (company_details, company_users) {
                next(vm => vm.setData(err, company_details, company_users))
            }));
    },
```

Am I on the right track ? The only thing I see here is I fell I'm required to call only one function `setData` in the `next` with all the parameters received from the different AJAX calls.

Is there a way to call several functions like `setUsers()`, `setDetails()` in the `next` ?

Is there a better way than what I'm doing ?

Comment: `next` is simply taking in an anonymous function (using arrow notation). You can make any number of calls you want in it

Comment: `next(vm => vm.setUsers(err, company_users) vm => vm.setDetails(err, company_details))` like this ?

Comment: next((vm) => { vm.setUser(err, company_users); vm.setDetails(err, company_details); })

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @thanksd stated :

`next((vm) => { vm.setUser(err, company_users); vm.setDetails(err, company_details); })`

The final answer is then

```
beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {

        function getCompanyDetails() {
            return  axios.get('/getCompanyDetails')    
        }

        function getUsers() {
            return axios.get('/getusers');
        }

        axios.all([getCompanyDetails(), getUsers()])
            .then(axios.spread(function (company_details, company_users) {
                next((vm) => { vm.setUser(err, company_users); vm.setDetails(err, company_details); })
            }));
    },
```